# warning: branch has multiple values and pull also fails

Tags: git, github

I used to have an old branch 201.  I removed it both locally and on the remote.

I now have a local branch called 201-me.  I tried to rename it locally and did, but then renamed it back to 201-me again.

But now I can't set it upstream to 201-me, I get:

```
company/app/app-api  201-me ✔                                                                                                                                                                                 2h5m  ⍉
▶ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/201-me
warning: branch.201-me.remote has multiple values
warning: branch.201-me.merge has multiple values
Branch 201-me set up to track remote branch 201-me from origin.

company/app/app-api  201-me ✔                                                                                                                                                                                  2h6m  
▶ git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/201'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

▶ git branch -vv
* 201-me ef4632c [origin/201: ahead 10, behind 1]  

company/app/app-api  201-me ✔                                                                                                                                                                                 2h13m  
▶ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 8), reused 10 (delta 8), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/201'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

Comment: Have you looked at ``.git/config`` in a text editor? See if you find any funny stuff there and edit manually.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, I had 2 entries in ./git/config:

```
[branch "201-me"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/201

[branch "201-me"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/201
```

so deleted one of them and then fixed it:

```
[branch "201-me"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/201-me
```